# mediawiki-parsoid "name lookup timed out" error

Tags: node.js, curl, heroku, mediawiki, visual-editor

At short - I am getting an error regarding `name lookup timed out` and don't understand where to search for the problem.

The long story - I've been trying to install MediaWiki Visual Editor, and launched a [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/home) based node.js parsoid server for that. I was running the experimental wiki both on localhost and in [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/), and it all worked great. However, when I tried to launch it in my main wiki, the editor failed in completing the "round-trip" (wiki-text > html > wiki-text) with the following results:

- **When re-editing, the editor "forgot" last time edits**
- **Error message** - After repeating this action three or four times it resulted in the following error message: `parsoid-server-http-request-error: "name lookup timed out"`.

My main assumption was that it had to do with some inability to cURL the other sever, and therefor tried to make cURL request around the trip but it all worked out with no problem. could it be a firewall I am not aware of?
Second assumption - something to do with server side to client side cache.

Any clue where to search for will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what solved this:

- shortened the heroku app url
- added time (3000) to `$wgHTTPConnectTimeout` and `$wgHTTPTimeout.` 
  The "forgetting" problem mentioned was due to client side cache.

Comment: Typo "forgeting", please fix.